# How fit content to table size

Tags: php, css, html-table

I'm looking for a way to fit table content to table size.
For example, I have table with width and height =100, and 5 col and 5 row, if row or col change to 20 only content re-size to fit into old table size.
I wrote some code,
but it resize table if row or col change!

```
<style>
.tbl {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.blck {
    border: 1px solid #0F3;
    background:#F00;    
}
.wht {
    border: 1px solid #0F3;
    background:#069;
}
</style>
<?php
$w = 15;
$h = 15;
$max = 100;

if ($w>=$h) {
    $cell = ($max/$w);
} else {
    $cell = ($max/$h);
}
$clr = 0;
$tbl .= '<table width="'.$max.'px" align="center" border="0" height="'.$max.'px" class="tbl">';
for ($r=1;$r<=$h;$r++){

$tbl .= '<tr>';
    for($c=1;$c<=$w;$c++){
        if($clr == '0'){
            $tbl .= '<td width="'.$cell.'%" height="'.$cell.'%" class="blck"></td>';
            $clr = 1;
        } else {
            $tbl .= '<td width="'.$cell.'%" height="'.$cell.'%" class="wht"></td>';
            $clr = 0;
        }
    }
$tbl .= '</tr>';
}

$tbl .= '</table>';

echo $tbl;

?>
```

Comment: $w is number of row and $h is number of col

Comment: can you use non fixed width and let the browser size as needed?

Comment: I'm working on crossword and i want to display a mini of puzzle for review and want it to be in fix size, not more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be careful when you add borders to the table cells, because it will add 2px to the current width/height.
use floor() when you divide the table width by cols/rows count, because width and height attributes doesn't accept fractions.

And it seems that  height attribute is not accurate (no idea why).

Also you have to consider text size. for example i put:

```
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 1px;
```

Check this out:

```
<?php
$w = 30;
$h = 30;
$max = 100;

if ($w>=$h) {
    $cell = floor($max/$w);
} else {
    $cell = floor($max/$h);
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
.tbl {
    display: table;
    height: <?php echo ($cell*$h); ?>px;
    width: <?php echo ($cell*$w); ?>px;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
}
.blck {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.wht {
    background-color: #069;
}

.tbl .tr {
    display: table-row;
}

.tbl .td {
    width: <?php echo $cell;?>px;
    height: <?php echo $cell;?>px;
    display: table-cell;
}
</style>
<?php 

$fcell = $clr = 0;
$tbl .= '<div class="tbl">';
for ($r=1;$r<=$h;$r++){
    $tbl .= '<div class="tr">';
        for($c=1;$c<=$w;$c++){
            if($clr == '0'){
                $tbl .= '<div class="td blck">&nbsp;</div>';
                $clr = 1;
            } else {
                $tbl .= '<div class="td wht">&nbsp;</div>';
                $clr = 0;
            }
        }
    $tbl .= '</div>';

    if ($fcell == 0){
        $fcell = $clr = 1;
    } else {
        $fcell = $clr = 0;
    }
}

$tbl .= '</div>';

echo $tbl;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly you want to manage the size of the table in your own logic.
if any content in a cell of the table should overflow for some reason you don't want it to grow. you want it to stay static in that case try adding this attribute

```
table
{
   table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Mortalus: it fix table width but not content, and content get overflow from table, the code work for row or col less 15 but not for more

Comment: actually i forgot to say: code work for less than 15 row or col but i want to work for 30 col or row.

Comment: I'm not mean that, I mean to re-size content to fit in fix size without changing table height or width. for example change td and tr to smaller size. sorry my English is not good enough. Hope you understand what i say and what i want to do